# Trapping a convex body by a finite set of points

Tags: discrete-geometry, convexity

In $\mathbb{R}^n$, let $K$ be a convex body and $T$ a finite set of points disjoint from the interior of $K$. Say that $T$ *traps* $K$ if there is no continuous motion of $K$ carrying $K$ arbitrarily far away from its original position during which no point of $T$ penetrates the interior of $K$. Is there a finite number $k=k(n)$ such that each $n$-dimensional convex body $K$ can be trapped by a set of at most $k$ points? If so, what is the smallest such $k$?  Observe that the $3$-cube can be trapped by six points, but not by five (for the $n$-cube it's $2n$ points, but not $2n-1$). The $n$-ball can be trapped by $n+1$ points, and it seems that no $n$-dimensional convex body can be trapped by $n$ points.

The main question is: **Can every convex body in $\mathbb{R}^3$ be trapped by six points?**

More generally: **Can every convex body in $\mathbb{R}^n$ be trapped by $2n$ points?**

Footnote 1. Here is a variation of the problem, perhaps easier to handle: restrict the motions of $K$ to parallel translations.

Footnote 2. For $n=2$, a closely related problem, namely of immobilizing the body with a finite set of points, has been studied and solved: four points always suffice. Reference will be provided upon request (I will have to look it up).

Comment: In the translation case:  I wonder if there is an argument which inducts on the dimension, say by using two points defining a "width" of $K$, followed by restriction to an orthogonal hyperplane.

Comment: @PeterDukes: For the version restricted to translations - perhaps so.

Comment: My argument -- if it even works -- may require $K$ smooth.  By the way, are there interesting examples of bodies (not disks, for instance) when $r$ points suffice to trap it but no $r$ points immobilize it?

Comment: @PeterDukes: Nice question! The only reference on immobilization I know is the one given in Joseph O'Rourke's answer, but it deals with all rigid motions, not restricted to translations. In that sense, a body of revolution cannot be immobilized at all, by any number of points. I do not know of an example you're asking for, with respect to translations only. I would try to prove first that if $k$ points immobilize $K$, then some $k$ points *on the boundary of* $K$ immobilize $K$ as well, and the same for trapping, perhaps.

Comment: I just saw Yuliy Baryshnikov give a talk on related topics at the IMA (what he called "caging"). You might want to ask him for references.

Comment: @PeterDukes: For $K$ smooth, there are normals in all directions, and you can pick $n+1$ points on the surface whose unit normal vectors have the origin in the interior of their convex hull. Any small translation will move one of these points into the interior.

Comment: @GregFriedman: Thanks for the tip. Is Yuliy's talk the same, or similar to, what is shown on
http://dimacs.rutgers.edu/Events/2009/slides/DIS_Dec14_link_t.pdf  ?

Comment: @DouglasZare:  Yes, absolutely.  I am not sure if inducting on the dimension works always, but it certainly isn't best possible in the smooth case.  In general, I had the impression that one can usually do much better than $2n$.  PS:  Hi!  It's nice to see you again after all these years, even if just on MO!

Answer (score 4):

I will assume we are not allowing re-orientation of the body (rotation).

If one wishes to determine if some arbitrary rigid body $K$ can pass some obstacle $T$ without touching it, one can reduce the problem to determining if some point $k \in K$ can pass by the [Minkowski sum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minkowski_addition) of $K$ and $T$ (which I will denote $K+T$) without touching it. In this case, if we wish to determine if $K$ can escape to infinity, assuming $K$ is bounded and finite, we need only determine if $K+T$ disconnects $\mathbb{R}^n$ into at least two connected components.

Since $T$ is a set of points, $K + T$ is simply taking $|T|$ copies of $K$, where each copy is centered at a point in $T$ (you can pick any point in $K$ to be the "center" of $K$, WLOG). Our question then becomes: what is the shape that maximizes the number of copies we would need to union together (without rotations) to disconnect $\mathbb{R}^n$ into two non-empty sets, and how many copies would that be?

I am fairly certain that proving that the $n$-cube is this shape, and that it requires $2n$ copies is a hop and a skip away from this, but I'm at a loss for a sufficiently formal argument. Something about how the faces are orthogonal and can only restrict one direction in one dimension at a time or something, which is somehow the worst-case. There's probably a similar argument for n+1 being a lower bound and tetrahedra. Unfortunately, this is where my knowledge stops.

de Berg et al's *Computational Geometry: Algorithms and Applications* covers the Minkowski Sum stuff very well in *Chapter 13: Robot Motion Planning*.

Comment: This looks like a good approach to the "translations only" version.

Comment: @user111 editing large numbers of old questions pushes newer questions off the front page. Please stop.

Answer (score 3):

This is not an answer, just a reference on
*immobilizing* in $\mathbb{R}^3$:

---

[image: Immobilizing theorem]

---

> Bracho, J., Fetter, H., Mayer, D., & Montejano, L. (1995). Immobilization of solids and mondriga quadratic forms. *Journal of the London Mathematical Society*, **51**(1), 189-200.
>   ([ResearchGate link](http://www.researchgate.net/publication/235666570_Immobilization_of_solids_and_mondriga_quadratic_forms))

They cite one W. Kuperberg from a 1990 presentation. :-)